# How to align or mirror half armature

Tags: armature, add-on

I have installed Rigify Addon added the armature and scale and align the half of my mesh. I want to align the other half is there any option or mirror way the half armature. Any help or suggestion. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In edit mode, you can access to the "symmetrize" function:

- Select the left part of the character
- The use the menu "Armature">"Symmetrize"

It will work if the bones are correctly named (".L" or ".Left" suffix for the left part, ".R" or ".Right" for the right part).

[image]

Note that it is working also if the bones are not already created:

[image]

You can also use the "X axis mirror" option:

[image]

Note: all these functions work well if the armature is along X with no rotation. So if you have rotations, apply them before <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choose rotation)

Comment: Thats what i need

Comment: You may also delete the right part of the character, then select the left side, pess *Shift+C* (or *Shift+S* --> *Cursor to Selected* - with a *pivot point type* set to *3D cursor*), then *Shift+D*, *Ctrl+M*, *X*. It'll mirror the selected bones along the X axis.